# Div com height igual ao background-image

Tags: css

Estou com uma div e nela existe um `background-image` de `height` variante, eu gostaria que essa div tivesse exatamente o mesmo `height` desta imagem, para que ela não fique cortada.

É algo assim:

```
<div style="background-image: url(..); height:100%;"></div>
```

A imagem pode ter `height` > 1000 que a div fica 0 de `height`, como solucionar?

Answer (score 0):

A única forma é se o aspect-ratio de todas as imagens for o mesmo, então você pode fazer isso:

```css
.fundo {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-size: contain;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/67/Wiki-llama.jpg/1600px-Wiki-llama.jpg') top center no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.fundo:after {
  padding-top: 75%;
  /* essa lhama tem tamanho 800x600 então setamos um padding-top % equivalente a 600/800, ou .75, ele cria um height usando o padding para a div n colapsar */
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
.conteudo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fundo">
  <div class="conteudo">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ut rhoncus mauris. Sed a lorem vehicula, mattis massa ac, faucibus tortor. Pellentesque lobortis blandit ligula ut bibendum. Curabitur diam dolor, lacinia sit amet arcu sit amet, porta accumsan eros. Pellentesque dictum sed quam id aliquam. Donec a ultricies purus. Aenean vel eros congue, maximus justo non, mollis elit. Phasellus lobortis nunc at velit volutpat, vel sagittis est lobortis. Quisque id velit facilisis, dignissim sapien at, iaculis odio. Morbi in felis nec lorem luctus tincidunt. Fusce ornare sapien odio, a consequat dolor bibendum eget.
  </div>
</div>
```

Se as imagens são de tamanhos diferentes você vai precisar ler o tamanho da imagem após a renderização (no browser), e ajustar o height usando Javascript ou JQuery por exemplo. Também é possível fazer isso no back-end, antes de enviar os dados para o usuário (via PHP ou JSP por exemplo).

Se você puder alterar a estrutura do HTML, é muito melhor usar a tag image para isso, pois ela tem justamente essa função (de imagem como um bloco):

```css
div {
    position: relative;
}
div img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

div div {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/67/Wiki-llama.jpg/1600px-Wiki-llama.jpg" />
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ut rhoncus mauris. Sed a lorem vehicula, mattis massa ac, faucibus tortor. Pellentesque lobortis blandit ligula ut bibendum. Curabitur diam dolor, lacinia sit amet arcu sit amet, porta accumsan eros. Pellentesque dictum sed quam id aliquam. Donec a ultricies purus. Aenean vel eros congue, maximus justo non, mollis elit. Phasellus lobortis nunc at velit volutpat, vel sagittis est lobortis. Quisque id velit facilisis, dignissim sapien at, iaculis odio. Morbi in felis nec lorem luctus tincidunt. Fusce ornare sapien odio, a consequat dolor bibendum eget.</div>
</div>
```